# Multiple settings for separate Live Wallpapers

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

I have two Live Wallpapers that belong to the same Application and I am trying to have separate Preference settings for each one but I have run into the issue of the first settings being used by both Wallpapers.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <service
        android:label="first wallpaper"
        android:name="com.package.this1.number1"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/source1" />
    </service>

    <service
        android:label="second wallpaper"
        android:name="com.package.this2.number2"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper" android:resource="@xml/source2" />
    </service>

    <activity android:label="@string/settings"
        android:name=".this1.Settings1"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    </activity>

    <activity android:label="@string/settings"
        android:name=".this2.Settings2"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Am I missing something simple or is it not possible to do this without making 2 separate applications?

Here's the code of my Settings1 and Settings2 classes

```
public class Settings1 extends PreferenceActivity   implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(number1.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.this1_settings);
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

public class Settings2 extends PreferenceActivity   implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName(number2.SHARED_PREFS_NAME);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.this2_settings);
    getPreferenceManager().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moonblink (creator of Android Tricorder) also has a collection of live wallpapers called Substrate.  Substrate does indeed combine multiple wallpapers into a single package, and more than one of the wallpapers has a settings activity.  I suggest you examine his structure.  Start here http://code.google.com/p/moonblink/source/browse/
and look for Substrate (under trunk).  Hope this helps.

P.S. The project home is here: http://code.google.com/p/moonblink/wiki/Substrate

Comment: I do have 2 seperate SHARED_PREFS_NAME, one in each of the wallpapers. They share the same name "SHARED_PREFS_NAME" with a different value ex. "wallpaperprefs1" and "wallpaperprefs2" but I explicitly reference in the separate PreferenceActivity as noted above. The other puzzling thing is that I use two separate XML settings, but the PreferenceActivity 1 is always used.

Comment: Ah ok, my fault. I just did as such to no avail, it still takes the first Preference Activity.

Comment: @Alejandro I found an example of someone doing this and edited my answer to provide the link.

Comment: This looks like what I'm trying to do, though not the simple solution I was hoping for, it is a far more robust one. Thank you for the great find.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I found the error in my original code. In the resource xml for the Preference Activity there was a android:settingsActivity="the first activity" which was referencing the same Activity, thus my error. Heh...

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks for clarifying.  This is a very frustrating and unforgiving programming environment. :-)